# Ti-Nspire missing ti-basic things

Tags: calculator, graphing, ti-basic, ti-nspire

I have a Ti-nspire graphing calculator that I bought online (the one that came out in 2006) I have been searching for quite a while and have found very little documentation online. I have wanted to code in Ti-basic for a while, which I was excited to do with this. However, it seems that things like the draw category, the getKey function, and many, many other things don’t work on this calculator. This makes it hard to code anything except a simple math program. The syntax also seems slightly different from the Ti 83/84. Is it possible to use those things on this calculator, or did I get the wrong one to help me learn TI-basic (that wasn’t the whole reason I bought it, but I thought it would be fun)? I mainly bought it because when I looked at a comparison chart of all of the TI calculators, this one seemed the best based on processor speed, memory, etc. And it was within my small budget.

I tried some scripts written for a TI 83/84 expecting it to work, but lots of the functions did not work.p

Comment: Well, you said it yourself; you compared apples with bananas and now realize that while both are fruit, they taste differently. You may find help on transitioning between these different platforms with their own TI-BASIC dialects on Cemetech but I've been too long out of the loop to have some links handy right now.

Comment: I did find that the calculator has a Ti-84 keypad you can put on which switches the OS, I might try that.

Comment: Did you find the Guide book and the Reference book for your calculator?
See  https://education.ti.com/en/guidebook/search/ti-nspire

Comment: @Codachrome lmao what do u mean it "switches the OS"?

Comment: It literally swaps the OS on the calculator to the ti-84.